# Difference usage of うまい and 上手?

Tags: word-choice, usage

I would like to tell that she is very good in Japanese . Which one is more suitable to use under sentences ...

```
彼女は日本語が[上手]{jouzu}です。
```

or

```
彼女は日本語がうまいです。
```

> Can I use both sentences ? Is there no particular differences ?